# Updating solid SVG file with a gradient

Tags: svg

I am trying to update a single color SVG file with a Gradient and would like to create a HeartBeat effect during the transition.  I created a SVG file and named it redSVG.svg  and then added it to an object so I can display it on the screen.

Here is my SVG file content (redSVG.svg):

```
<svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 735.4 525.28">
  <defs>
    <style>
      .cls-1{fill:#FF0000;}
      
        @keyframes pulse {
                0 %, 100 % {
                    transform: scale(1, 0.5);
                }
            }

            .cls-1 {
                    animation: pulse 3.5s infinite;
                    -webkit - animation: pulse 3.5s infinite;
            }

            @keyframes pulse {
                0 % {
                    fill: #8F00FF;                
            }

            15 % {
                fill: #FFA500;           

            }

            30 % {
                fill: #FFFF00;            

            }

            57 % {
                fill: #00FF00;            

            }

            71 % {
                fill: #1E1DF0;            

            }

            85 % {
                fill: #4B0082;            
    
            }

            100 % {
                fill: #FF0000;            
            }
    </style>
  </defs>
  <rect class="cls-1" width="735.4" height="525.28"/>
</svg>
```

Here is the object that I am using to call i

```
  <object id="color-change-svg" type="image/svg+xml"
        data="redSVG.svg" style="width: 43vh;height: 41vh;">
   </object>
```

I would like to change the Red color to a range of seven colors as a transition, and also create a Heartbeat effect in the process.  How should I adjust my SVG code to display the gradient 7 colors as a heartbeat?

Comment: Presumably you want either a linearGradient or a radialGradient depending on how you want it to look.

Comment: You [already know about gradients though](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71277424/updating-the-colors-of-a-gradient-svg-file) so what else can we tell you here?

Comment: I am having trouble getting a smooth gradient effect and would like some help with the transition timing and the heart beat effect.

Comment: OK, but there's no gradient at all in your question, so how can we see what your trouble getting s smooth gradient is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not completely sure what you are searching for. There can be only one `@keyframes pulse` definition and the percentage number and sign should have no space between them. SO, here the `@keyframes pulse` is handling both fill color and transform.

```html
<svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 735.4 525.28">
  <defs>
    <style>
      .cls-1 {
        fill: #FF0000;
      }

      .cls-1 {
        animation: pulse 3.5s infinite;
        -webkit-animation: pulse 3.5s infinite;
      }
      
      @keyframes pulse {
        0% {
          fill: #8F00FF;
          transform: scale(1);
        }
        15% {
          fill: #FFA500;
        }
        30% {
          fill: #FFFF00;
        }
        57% {
          fill: #00FF00;
          transform: scale(.5);
        }
        71% {
          fill: #1E1DF0;
        }
        85% {
          fill: #4B0082;
        }
        100% {
          fill: #FF0000;
          transform: scale(1);
        }
      }
    </style>
  </defs>
  <rect class="cls-1" width="735.4" height="525.28"/>
</svg>
```